# inequality $x > \left | \left | x \right | + \left | x-3 \right |+\left | x-5 \right |\right |+7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need help in this exercise because I got stuck in this inequality which I have to show that it has no solution, could someone give me an idea of ​​how to continue or finish it, please.
$$x > \left | \left | x \right | + \left | x-3 \right |+\left | x-5 \right |\right |+7$$

Comment: Why do you have absolute values inside an absolute value?

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the outer absolute value is unnecessary since all your values are positive, so your equation reduces to

$x > |x| + |x - 3| + |x - 5| + 7 $

From this, we can clearly see that the equation is impossible.

This is because:

$|x| + |x - 3| + |x - 5| + 7 > |x| + 7 > x$

Answer (score 1):

First observe $$x>7. \tag{1}$$ Then
$$ |x|=x,|x-3|=x-3,|x-5|=x-5 $$
and hence the inequality becomes
$$ x>3x-1$$
which implies 
$$ x<\frac12. \tag{2}$$
Note that (1) and (2) are contradictory with each other. So the inequality has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The RHS is a piecewise linear function, which is continuous. It suffices to check inequality at the angular points and outside.

- $x\le0\to x>|-x-(x-3)-(x-5)|+7$ is certainly impossible,
- $x=3\to 3>|3+0+2|+7$ does not hold,
- $x\ge5\to x>|x+x+2+x-5|+7$ is certainly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you just logically look at it, it’s obviously not always true, thus you can prove it is not true by giving a counter example.